# An SQL Query works fine when executed, But the same Query if I'm using in a PL/SQL it shows error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Hi I've the following query which works fine in SQL, I mean it gets executed successfully.

```
SELECT id_ligne, n_res_id, n_rty_id, NVL (res_va_text, va_res_txt),
       NVL (res_va_short_name, va_res_short_name), bl_has_bo, bl_asset,
       bl_needs_profile, bl_update_name, bl_popup_mandatory, va_popup_name,
       va_itrack_create, va_itrack_delete, va_generic_mail,
       n_application_type, bl_mono_profile
  FROM t_t_actres_ea4, t_resource_ea4
 WHERE res_n_id(+) = n_res_id
   AND t_t_actres_ea4.id_ligne NOT IN (
          SELECT DISTINCT (t_erralim_ea4.err_n_lineid)
                     FROM t_erralim_ea4
                    WHERE 0235303 = t_erralim_ea4.err_n_code_trt
                      AND err_n_rejecttype = 0)
```

It gets executed and the desired output is fetched. But when I use the same query for the PL/SQL like below.

```
L_REQ Varchar2(1000) := 'select ID_LIGNE, N_RES_ID, N_RTY_ID, NVL(RES_VA_TEXT,VA_RES_TXT),NVL(RES_VA_SHORT_NAME,VA_RES_SHORT_NAME), '||
' BL_HAS_BO, BL_ASSET, BL_NEEDS_PROFILE, BL_UPDATE_NAME, BL_POPUP_MANDATORY, VA_POPUP_NAME, ' ||
' VA_ITRACK_CREATE, VA_ITRACK_DELETE, VA_GENERIC_MAIL, N_APPLICATION_TYPE, BL_MONO_PROFILE ' ||
' from T_T_ACTRES_EA4, T_RESOURCE_EA4  ' ||
' where RES_N_ID (+) = N_RES_ID AND T_T_ACTRES_EA4.ID_LIGNE not in ( select distinct(T_ERRALIM_EA4.ERR_N_LINEID) ' ||
' from T_ERRALIM_EA4 ' ||
' where 0235307 = T_ERRALIM_EA4.ERR_N_CODE_TRT AND ERR_N_REJECTTYPE = 0 and T_ERRALIM_EA4.ERR_VA_MSG  not like ''Mono-profile%'')';
```

It gives me the error saying **ORA-00936: missing expression**

> Note: This error is caused when I append this conditon to the sub-query. 
>   **and T_ERRALIM_EA4.ERR_VA_MSG  not like ''Mono-profile%''**

TIA.

Comment: That doesn't even compile successfully.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here. If you're tying to store the result set from select statement in a variable `L_REQ` then it's certainly not the right way.

Comment: Unrelated: but you should really stop those outdated implicit joins in the `where` clause and use a proper `JOIN` clause - especially for outer joins.

Comment: I'm guessing you're doing an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE L_REQ` somewhere. Please edit your question and include the code that actually executes this query. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming what you provided is what you want, no execute immediate: it cannot compile.

You have

```
variable declaration := sql statement
```

You should have

```
DECLARE
  variable declaration
BEGIN
  sql statement
END;
```

The sql statement should have SELECT INTO syntax

```
SELECT id_ligne, n_res_id, n_rty_id, NVL (res_va_text, va_res_txt),
       NVL (res_va_short_name, va_res_short_name), bl_has_bo, bl_asset,
       bl_needs_profile, bl_update_name, bl_popup_mandatory, va_popup_name,
       va_itrack_create, va_itrack_delete, va_generic_mail,
       n_application_type, bl_mono_profile
  INTO LREQ
  FROM t_t_actres_ea4, t_resource_ea4
 WHERE res_n_id(+) = n_res_id
   AND t_t_actres_ea4.id_ligne NOT IN (
          SELECT DISTINCT (t_erralim_ea4.err_n_lineid)
                     FROM t_erralim_ea4
                    WHERE 0235303 = t_erralim_ea4.err_n_code_trt
                      AND err_n_rejecttype = 0);
```

@Bob Jarvis is spot on also - you could do

```
DECLARE
 L_REQ Varchar2(1000) := 'select ID_LIGNE, N_RES_ID, N_RTY_ID, NVL(RES_VA_TEXT,VA_RES_TXT),NVL(RES_VA_SHORT_NAME,VA_RES_SHORT_NAME), '||
' BL_HAS_BO, BL_ASSET, BL_NEEDS_PROFILE, BL_UPDATE_NAME, BL_POPUP_MANDATORY, VA_POPUP_NAME, ' ||
' VA_ITRACK_CREATE, VA_ITRACK_DELETE, VA_GENERIC_MAIL, N_APPLICATION_TYPE, BL_MONO_PROFILE ' ||
' from T_T_ACTRES_EA4, T_RESOURCE_EA4  ' ||
' where RES_N_ID (+) = N_RES_ID AND T_T_ACTRES_EA4.ID_LIGNE not in ( select distinct(T_ERRALIM_EA4.ERR_N_LINEID) ' ||
' from T_ERRALIM_EA4 ' ||
' where 0235307 = T_ERRALIM_EA4.ERR_N_CODE_TRT AND ERR_N_REJECTTYPE = 0 and T_ERRALIM_EA4.ERR_VA_MSG  not like ''Mono-profile%'')';
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE L_REQ;
END;
```

This is probably not the best choice, static SQL offers better performance a lot of the time.